# selecting column N of matrix/dataframe where N is based on another vector

Tags: r

I have a dataframe X with several columns and want to select column N for each row where N is different for each row depending on some vector ( in this example : values in column sel)

```
    A   B   C   D   sel
16/04/2012  NA  -1.25   -1.25   0.25    1
17/04/2012  NA  20  21.25   17.25   1
18/04/2012  -5.25   -5.25   -5.75   -1  2
19/04/2012  -6  -6  -6.25   -12 2
20/04/2012  2.5 2.5 2.75    NA  2
23/04/2012  NA  -12.25  -12 NA  2
24/04/2012  NA  7.25    7.5 7.25    2
25/04/2012  NA  17.5    17  18.25   4
26/04/2012  NA  9.5 10  11.5    4
27/04/2012  NA  2   1   -3.25   4
30/04/2012  NA  -4.75   -4  -1  4
01/05/2012  NA  6.25    5.75    17  3
02/05/2012  NA  -3  -2.75   -16 3
03/05/2012  NA  -11.5   -11.5   -6.75   4
04/05/2012  NA  -23.5   -23.75  -23 4
```

so i would end up with

```
16/04/2012  NA
17/04/2012  NA
18/04/2012  -5.25
19/04/2012  -6
20/04/2012  2.5
23/04/2012  -12.25
24/04/2012  7.25
25/04/2012  18.25
26/04/2012  11.5
27/04/2012  -3.25
30/04/2012  -1
01/05/2012  5.75
02/05/2012  -2.75
03/05/2012  -6.75
04/05/2012  -23
```

`X[,X$sel]` 
gave me a square matrix equal to `nrow(X)`, not quite what i need.

is there some sort of "Excel's INDEX' type of functions i can use maybe inside an apply function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the method of [subsetting](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Subsetting.html#data-types) a data frame by passing a two-column matrix with row numbers in the first column and column numbers in the second column. So:

```
X[matrix(ncol=2, c(1:nrow(X), X$sel)]
```

will give you a vector of those selected elements, which you can then build into whatever result data frame you're aiming for. Or just add to the existing data frame like this:

```
X$selected_values <- X[matrix(ncol=2, c(1:nrow(X), X$sel)]
```